# Element-wise product of a matrix by a vector

Tags: matrices, terminology

Suppose I have an $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, and a column $m$-vector $\mathbf{v}$. Let $\mathbf{B}$ represents the matrix resulted from the element-wise multiplication of each column of $\mathbf{A}$ with the vector $\mathbf{v}$. For example,

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\
v_{2} \\
v_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\mathbf{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} v_{1} & a_{12} v_{1} \\
a_{21} v_{2} & a_{22} v_{2} \\
a_{31} v_{3} & a_{32} v_{3} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

What do we call this kind of multiplication? Is it a Hadamard product?

Comment: I'm not sure what to call this, but it's not quite a Hadamard product. The Hadamard product is typically defined as element-wise multiplication of two matrices of the same size. This might not have an agreed upon name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ {\bf B} = \operatorname{diag} ({\bf v}) \, {\bf A} $$

Comment: You can also write it using a Hadamard product as
$\,\large{B = A\odot (v{\tt1}^T)}\;$

Comment: @greg That would be worthy of an answer

Comment: I agree with you, but I just want to know if there is a common name for this operation.

Comment: @EsamMoh One could call it *row-weighting*.